# How to get value (from date - to date) from date-range date picker in material angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, angular6

I passed the dates from component to template date picker. Here my question is how to get value from template(**HTML**) to component (**TS**) file. Like below

`startDate = new Date() || selected start date from date picker
endDate = new Date(2019, 1, 20) || selected end date form date picker`

**TypeScript:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  startDate = new Date();
  endDate = new Date(2019, 1, 20);
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      date: [{begin: this.startDate, end: this.endDate}]
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput 
      placeholder="Choose a date" 
      [satDatepicker]="picker" 
      formControlName="date">
    <sat-datepicker-toggle 
      matSuffix 
      [for]="picker">
    </sat-datepicker-toggle>
    <sat-datepicker 
      #picker 
      [rangeMode]="true" 
      touchUi="true">
    </sat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here first I am passing the date by default but once date will select another range I don't know how to get the value on selected or on changing the value.
I tried **ngModel** but didn't get the value from a variable. Here I mentioned Stackblitz project link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gx6xx

Answer (score 1):

To get selected dates from daterangepicker material.
Call (datesUpdated) api in template.

template:

```
<input ngxDaterangepickerMd (datesUpdated)="datesUpdated($event)"> <input>
```

ts:

```
datesUpdated(range){
console.log(range.startDate._d);
console.log(range.endDate._d);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just add

```
this.form.get('date').valueChanges
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

in constructor
or 
use

`this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => console.log(res));`

and you can also add validate feature or other something

```
import { filter, map, startWith  } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
....
   this.form.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      filter(() => this.form.valid),
      map(data => {
        // append last update time to result
        data.lastTime = new Date();
        return data;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```